# How to run a script (pointing to a python file) with root permission at startup in Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: raspbian-buster, bash, cron, init.d

I am trying to run a script which ultimately runs a pagekite python file. The [Pagekite](https://pagekite.net/) offers tunnelling service for localhost to be publicly accessible. My aim is to run the pagekite.py when the Pi is booted and the website is up and running. I am trying to run the script with root permissions. I tried using two approaches:

1. Using the `# crontab -e` with root privileges and [adding](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57835/why-my-script-is-not-executed-with-root-privileges-using-crontab) `@reboot bash -x /home/username/myscript.sh` in crontab file
2. Adding the script file in `/etc/init.d` and creating symlink with `sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/myscript.sh /etc/rc.d/`.

However none of these approaches tend to work. Please note, I have kept the python file in the same location as of the script (Earlier, I even tried adding the `cd` command to the destination folder containing `pagekite.py` in `myscript.sh` script.). Also sudo is needed in the prefix for running the python script. After attempting the reboot, nothing happens and the web page is unreachable.Apart from that, is it possible to run the script automatically and display the kite status in the terminal, like the one we get if we manually run the pagekite script ? Check the image below for what I mean by "kite status in terminal window"

Contents of `myscript.sh` file

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo python3 pagekite.py 80 furball.pagekite.me
```

Contents of `sudo crontab -e`

```
@reboot sudo bash -x /home/username/Desktop/myscript.sh
```

The py file and sh are both present in same directory.

[image: Source: pagekite.net]

Comment: Have you successfully run your script from the command line?

Comment: @Seamus Yes. The website is operational once the raspberry pi boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the contents of the myscript.sh file are :

#!/bin/sh
sudo python3 pagekite.py 80 furball.pagekite.me

I suggest that you also add full paths for all the above, including python.

I.e. :

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/python3 <full pagekite.py path>/pagekite.py 80 <full furball.pagekite.me path>/furball.pagekite.me
```

At any case, run also a :

```
cat /var/log/syslog|grep cron
```

that might give you a clue on what goes wrong...

Comment: Thanks a ton ! This worked, I think adding the paths for each file in `myscipt.sh` and ` sudo crontab -e` enabled each one of them to work as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach may not work because

- `bash` is not fully qualified and `cron`'s path may not include `/usr/bin`
- `-X` is not a valid `bash` option.
- there may be a permission problem preventing `cron` from accessing your script
- The network may not be up yet when the job is executed. You could try to delay it a little bit with `bash -c 'sleep 60 && /home/username/myscript.sh'`

Your second approach will not work because:

- `/etc/rc.d` is not a valid SysV name. You probably meant `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc5.d`.
- SysV is not used anymore. SystemD (which took its place) tries to keep the compatibility by running some of the SysV scripts, but it cannot run all of them correctly, and it cannot run them in the correct order. In your case, you most probably need network connection before your script starts.

Look into how SystemD units are [written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started), and write one with `After=network-online.target` in it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your ***headline*** question: `How to run a script (pointing to a python file) with root permission at startup in Raspberry Pi OS?`:

I don't know what you tried because your question is unclear to me, but if `root` privileges are required to run a script at start/boot on RPi, here's how to do that:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

This will present the `root crontab` in your default editor. Once in the editor, to run a script at start/boot, use the `@reboot` facility:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script
```

That will do it. If you're having issues beyond that, you will have to provide more details if you want help. The answer you referenced is *misleading* at best because, like you, the OP provided **no details** of the script he was trying to run.

Likewise, we can't help you with your `bash -X` because the `-X` option applies to a *filter specification* used in `bash`'s word completion feature, and it looks out-of-place as you've used it in your question

Other than that, the instructions above, as applied to what you say you've tried look like this in your `root crontab` file:

```
@reboot bash /home/username/myscript.sh
```

When you reboot your system, it will most certainly execute the script at `/home/username/myscript.sh` with root privileges. Again, if you're not getting the result you hoped for, we need more information to help you.

Alternatively, as this seems slightly off-topic for Raspberry Pi, you might consider asking your question in another forum.

Comment: My deepest apologies. I changed the command from `@reboot bash -x /home/username/myscript.sh` in the question. This was a typo. Also, I have added the contents of .sh file and `crontab -e` in the question. By `bash -x`, the option -x stands for `Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.` . I got this information from `man bash`. What exactly I need is the command is not executed after reboot (which it should, because of @reboot).